# YouTube live Stream partially working on android

Tags: android, youtube, youtube-api, live-streaming

I finally got YouTube live streaming to play on my app, the only inconvenience is when I go into full screen mode the player stops and it doesn't play anymore, also sometimes when I stop the player and try to play again it plays for 2 seconds then stops, I know YouTube live is on beta stage but that doesn't mean we couldn't find a solution for this, does anybody have any suggestions on how to solve this issue?

LiveYouTube.java

```
public class LiveYouTube extends YouTubeBaseActivity implements YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener {
public static final String API_KEY = "AIzaSyBMwV1heA9q75LkybRCK5SXXTJWADRtmDh4";

//http://youtu.be/<VIDEO_ID>
public static final String VIDEO_ID = "URS94beDtJA";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    /** attaching layout xml **/
    setContentView(R.layout.youtubelive);

    /** Initializing YouTube player view **/
    YouTubePlayerView youTubePlayerView = (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.youtube_player);
    youTubePlayerView.initialize(API_KEY, this);
}

@Override
public void onInitializationFailure(Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult result) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Failured to Initialize!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
public void onInitializationSuccess(Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored) {
    /** add listeners to YouTubePlayer instance **/
    player.setPlayerStateChangeListener(playerStateChangeListener);
    player.setPlaybackEventListener(playbackEventListener);

    /** Start buffering **/
    if (!wasRestored) {
        player.cueVideo(VIDEO_ID);
    }
}

private PlaybackEventListener playbackEventListener = new PlaybackEventListener() {

    @Override
    public void onBuffering(boolean arg0) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onPaused() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onPlaying() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onSeekTo(int arg0) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onStopped() {
    }

};

private PlayerStateChangeListener playerStateChangeListener = new PlayerStateChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onAdStarted() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(ErrorReason arg0) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaded(String arg0) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoading() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onVideoEnded() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onVideoStarted() {
    }
};
```

youtubelive.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rel"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/play_list_row_height"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="#c00311" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="LIVE VIDEO"
        android:textColor="@color/video_descrption_top_bar_text"
        android:textSize="@dimen/video_view_top_bar_font_size"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</RelativeLayout>

<com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
    android:id="@+id/youtube_player"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#fff"
    android:padding="0dp" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/logo"
    android:layout_width="340dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="-13dp"
    android:src="@drawable/shadow_line" />
```

Comment: Will this help ? http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-youtube-client-on-android--cms-22858  or http://www.androidhive.info/2014/12/how-to-play-youtube-video-in-android-app/

Comment: Nothing work my guess is since YouTube Live streaming is still on beta stage they may be still working on some stuff.